# Hide div when jquery condition is met does not work

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I have the following div that is supposed to be hidden to start with.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" style="display: none;" id="alertDiv"> <strong>Note!</strong><p>At the moment we cannot accept any players born 05 or earlier beacuse we currently are too many.</p></div>
```

When a user enter a numeric value in text field "membership-form-personumber" I want to check the value with jquery and show the div above if the criterias in the function is met, but it does not work. The div is never displayed even though I enter 2007 for example. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#membership-form-personumber').on('keyup change', function(c) {

    //initially hide all
    if(this.value.length < 4){
        $('#alertDiv').hide();
    }
    else{

        switch(parseInt(this.value)){

            case 2019: case 2018: case 2017: case 2016: case 2015: $('#alertDiv').show(); break;
            case 2014: case 2013: case 2012: case 2011: case 2010: $('#alertDiv').show(); break;
            case 2009: case 2008: case 2007: $('#alertDiv').show(); break;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: User $( "#membership-form-personumber" ).keyup(function() { instead of '$('#membership-form-personumber').on('keyup change', function(c) {'

Comment: @RaviKumar keyup and change is required. They are similar, but differ. `keyup` only won't capture browser autofill. `change` only will only fire when the textbox loses focus.

Comment: Your example works fine for me. See this https://jsfiddle.net/L8wrnakm/ Try to break this problem down so you can troubleshoot it. First, using the debugger see if the case for 2007 ends up invoking `$('#alertDiv.show()`. If it is then your event handler is working properly and something else is overriding the showing of the alert. Might be other CSS. You can use the chrome inspector to see what style is overriding it.

Comment: Once you get good at breaking down problems to troubleshoot you'll likely end up rarely needing to ask questions on Stackoverflow anymore.

Comment: If I change to $("#membership-form-personumber").keyup(function(){ nothing happend at all...

Answer (score 0):

Update: Hope I understood the issue correctly now. Added one line in my code snippet below that should fix the issue.

```
default: $('#alertDiv').hide();
```

Tested your code in Firefox 69.0.2 and it worked. See my test page where I copy&pasted your code below.

Did you check the developer console of your browser for Javascript errors preventing the script from executing properly?

Maybe your page is not yet completely loaded when your Javascript already executes and tries to access DOM nodes which do not exist yet. Are you wrapping you real code in a document.ready call? See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Regarding the code in general: Is there any business reason why you go with a switch statement here instead of a single if-statement checking if the value is lower or equal to 2005? Something like this:

```
if (parseInt(this.value) < 2005) {
    $('#alertDiv').show();
} else {
    $('#alertDiv').hide();
}
```

```js
$('#membership-form-personumber').on('keyup change', function (c) {

    //initially hide all
    if (this.value.length < 4) {
        $('#alertDiv').hide();
    }
    else {

        switch (parseInt(this.value)) {

            case 2019: case 2018: case 2017: case 2016: case 2015: $('#alertDiv').show(); break;
            case 2014: case 2013: case 2012: case 2011: case 2010: $('#alertDiv').show(); break;
            case 2009: case 2008: case 2007: $('#alertDiv').show(); break;
            // This line should fix your issue
            default: $('#alertDiv').hide();
        }

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" style="display: none;" id="alertDiv"> <strong>Note!</strong>
        <p>At the moment we cannot accept any players born 05 or earlier beacuse we currently are too many.</p>
    </div>
    <input id="membership-form-personumber">
</form>
```

Comment: I have it like that beacuse I want to trigger it on specific years. And yes the code you provided works but it does not hide the div if I enter a valid number

Comment: Thank you for your coment. Now I get your point. Will update my answer.

Comment: I see that the reason it didn't work for me is that I used autofill and the function only check the numbers if there is 4 digits. I need to also allow the user to add more numbers. So the user can add 20080201-1234, I need to validate the four first digits.